# Mobile CSS not appearing as intended

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[Check this image and screenshot](http://www.grafdom.com/operations/projects/ma/blue-error.png).

When select, hover or click the link then its show blue background on this mobile site, I already added the below code in my CSS.

Below is the working CSS code in desktop browsers but not in mobile, hover and other classes already defined.

Want to remove this default blue background, i not want this blue background other all things working fine

```
::-moz-selection {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #fff;
}
::selection {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #fff; 
}
```

Comment: OP, we've edited your question for you. If you can ask questions formatted like that (paragraphed, concise title, code formatting) that'd be great!

Comment: What do you want to achieve exactly? What does this CSS code have to do either click, hover or links at all?

Comment: I want this blue background not show on hover or click. Mean i want to remove this background issue

Comment: In my screenshot you check come default blue background, I want remove this background

Comment: I got the solution Just add the below code in your css      html {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution Just add the below code in your css 
    html { -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); }